# what will happen if Http response is not consumed and connection not closed?

Tags: apache, http

I am using below java classes for remote call.

> org.apache.http.HttpResponse
>   org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

My code snippet goes as follows.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Now what will happen if I don't consume the response and do not close the connection??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't consume the response will happen just nothing. All the message data is already in the client. If you don't close the connection also nothing because it is usually the server the one that closes the connection after sending the response unless the client sets the header:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Even when you set this header, after some timeout configured in the server, it will close the connection.